# SSLHandshakeException happens during file upload to AWS S3 via Alpakka

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I'm trying to setup an Alpakka S3 for files upload purpose. Here is my configs:

alpakka s3 dependency:

```
...
"com.lightbend.akka" %% "akka-stream-alpakka-s3" % "0.20"
...
```

Here is `application.conf`:

```
akka.stream.alpakka.s3 {
  buffer = "memory"
  proxy {
    host = ""
    port = 8000
    secure = true
  }
  aws {
    credentials {
      provider = default
    }
  }
  path-style-access = false
  list-bucket-api-version = 2
}
```

File upload code example:

```
private val awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("my_key", "my_secret_key")
private val awsCredentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)
private val regionProvider = new AwsRegionProvider { def getRegion: String = "us-east-1" }
private val settings = new S3Settings(MemoryBufferType, None, awsCredentialsProvider, regionProvider, false, None, ListBucketVersion2)
private val s3Client = new S3Client(settings)(system, materializer)

val fileSource = Source.fromFuture(ByteString("ololo blabla bla"))
val fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString

val s3Sink: Sink[ByteString, Future[MultipartUploadResult]] = s3Client.multipartUpload("my_basket", fileName)

fileSource.runWith(s3Sink)
  .map { 
    result => println(s"${result.location}") 
  } recover {
    case ex: Exception =>  println(s"$ex")
  }
```

When I run this code I get:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem`

What can be a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate problem arises for bucket names containing dots.
You may switch to 
`akka.stream.alpakka.s3.path-style-access = true` to get rid of this.

We're considering making it the default: https://github.com/akka/alpakka/issues/1152